# prove operator is ajoint of another operator

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach space, and $B\in B(X^{*},Y^{*})$ where $B(X^{*},Y^{*})$ are linear bounded operators from dual space of $X$ to dual space of $Y$. If $B$ is weak$^{*}$ continuous, prove that there is a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ $A$ such that $A^{*}=B$.

In order to find $A$, we have to make sure that for every $x$ and $y^{*}\in Y^{*}$, there is a $y$ such that $y^{*}(y)=B(y^{*})(x)$. I don't know how to make use of weak$^{*}$ continuous to prove this claim.

Comment: If $A:X\to Y$  then $B=A^*:Y^{*}\to X^{*}$ so I don't thinks this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you mean $A:Y\to X$  so that you want $A^*=B:X^{*}\to Y^{*}.$

If $B$ is  weak$^*$ continuous, then each $\text {eval}_y\circ B:X^*\to \mathbb C$ is a continuous linear functional on $X^*$, so it must be of the form $\text {eval}_{x}$ for some $x\in X$. Then, we have

$\tag1 \text {eval}_y\circ B(x'^{*})=B(x'^{*})(y)=\text {eval}_{x}(x'^{{*}})=x'^{{*}}(x).$

So if we define $A:Y\to X$ to be the operator that sends $y$ to the $x$ in $(1)$ we get

$\tag2 \langle y,Bx'^{*}\rangle=\langle x,x'^{{*}}\rangle=\langle Ay,x'^{{*}}\rangle$

which is the result.